# I have an array of objects with parameters(in hash). How can I list all the parameters of every object?

Tags: ruby

Item class

```
class Item

  def initialize(options = {})
    @name  = options[:name]
    @code  = options[:code]
    @category = options[:category]
    @size = options[:size]
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :code, :category, :size
end
```

Music class

```
class Music < Item
  def initialize(options = {})
    super
    @singer = options[:singer]
    @duration = options[:duration]
  end

  attr_accessor :singer, :duration
end
```

Movie class

```
  def initialize(options = {})
    super
    @director = options[:director]
    @main_actor   = options[:main_actor]
    @main_actress = options[:main_actress]
  end

  attr_accessor :director, :main_actor, :main_actress
end
```

```
class Catalog
  attr_reader :items_list

  def initialize
    @items_list = Array.new
  end

  def add(item)
    @items_list.push item
  end

  def remove(code)
    @items_list.delete_if { |i| i.code == code }
  end

  def show(code)
    # comming soon
  end

  def list
    @items_list.each do |array|
      array.each { |key, value| puts "#{key} => #{value}" }
    end
  end

end

catalog1 = Catalog.new
music1 = Music.new(name: "Venom", code: 1, category: :music, size: 1234, singer: "Some singer", duration: 195)
music2 = Music.new(name: "Champion of Death", code: 2, category: :music, size: 1234, singer: "Some singer", duration: 195)
catalog1.add(music1)
catalog1.add(music2)
```

ruby version 2.6.0
list method is not working. I got undefined method `each' for <#Music:0x0000562e8ebe9d18>.
How can I list all keys and values in another way? Like:
name - "Venom"
code - 1
category - music.
I was thinking about it, but also I got a Movie class and that method gonna be too long

Comment: I was thinking about it, but also I got a Movie class and that method gonna be too long.

Comment: You are missing `class Movie`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push instances of `Music` into `@items_list`. That means `@items_list.each` do not return an array, but instances of `Music` and that `Musik` instances do not respond do `each` nor they have keys and values.

I suggest adding an instance method to your `Music` class that returns the expected output. For example a `to_s` method like this:

```
def to_s
  "name \"#{name}\" code - #{code} category - #{category}"
end
```

and to change the `list` method in your `Catalog` to something like this:

```
def list
  @items_list.each do |music|
    puts music.to_s
  end
end
```

Or when you want to return the values an array of hashed then add a `to_h` method to `Music` like this:

```
def to_h
  { name: name, code: code, category: category }
end
```

and call it like this:

```
def list
  @items_list.map do |music|
    music.to_h
  end
end
```

Comment: or add an `each` method to `Catalog` since this is clearly a container. `def each(&block); return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?; @item_list.each(&block); end`. One could then include `Enumerable` if they wished although I personally would prefer `Catalog.each.enumerable_method_here` rather than including `Enumerable` everywhere